# Spring batch and basicdatasource issues when dealing with large files

Tags: multithreading, database-connection, spring-batch, batch-processing

We are using spring-batch to process multiple JSON files containing **30k** of rows each , using **MultiResourcePartioner**.Then the data is persisted into an Oracle Database.

The chunk commit interval is **1000** and we are using **taskExecutor** for multithreading.
Some problems  occurs in some environments (not mine ,so I couldn't reproduce the scenario) ,the batch stops after some amount of time:a thread stucks while trying to get db connection.

We reduced the chunk to 100 but the prolem still occurs.
Processing only 2 files or 3 files works, the problem is when dealing with more than 6 files.

Have you any recommendations to properly configure the batch to deal with all files without problems?

Thanks

Comment: could you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace would be great. Also, do you use a connection pooler ? I suppose the error happens in the writer ? Have you checked logs and locks on your database when this happens ?